# Gridview with Freeze Panes Horizontal and Vertical

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

Before you say, yeah this question can be duplicate;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912890/gridview-freeze-pane-solutions

[How to freeze GridView header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157528/how-to-freeze-gridview-header)

[Freeze GridView Header in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683628/freeze-gridview-header-in-asp-net)

[How To Freeze Columns in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093635/how-to-freeze-columns-in-gridview)

But there is no solution both freeze pane Horizontal and Vertical.

I have a `Gridview` like this.

[image]

Here is my `Gridview` code; (Sorry for long code)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames ="HESAP_NO,DOVIZ_KOD"
            Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Small" AllowSorting="True" 
         onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
         onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
         PageSize="2" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" 
         BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" >
        <Columns>

        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/images/InsertButton.gif"
         CommandName="Insert"  />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/images/SelectButton.gif"
         CommandName="Select"  />

         <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True"  ButtonType="Image" 
          EditImageUrl="~/images/EditButton.gif" cancelimageurl="~/images/CancelButton.gif"
            updateimageurl="~/images/UpdateButton.gif" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" >
          <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:CommandField>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HESAP" SortExpression="HESAP_NO">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HESAP_NO") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MÜŞTERİ" SortExpression="MUS_K_ISIM">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MUS_K_ISIM") %>'></asp:Label>

              <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlServerCstr %>" 
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO MEMO
                VALUES(@M_HESAP_NO, @S_TARIH, @S_TUTAR, @DOV_KOD, @G_NOT, @G_KISI, 4, 
                @login, GETDATE())"
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM MEMO A, P_SONUC B, P_KUR C
                WHERE A.S_SONUC = B.SONUC_KOD
                AND A.S_KUR = C.DOV_KOD
                AND B.LANG = 1 
                AND ([M_HESAP_NO] = @M_HESAP_NO)" 
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE MEMO
                SET S_SONUC = @SONUC_KOD
                WHERE NOT_ID = @NOT_ID"
                >

                <SelectParameters>
                  <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="M_HESAP_NO" QueryStringField="T_HESAP_NO" 
                    Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                  <asp:ControlParameter Name="M_HESAP_NO" ControlID="Label1" PropertyName="Text" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="S_TARIH" Type="DateTime"/>
                  <asp:Parameter Name="S_TUTAR" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="DOV_KOD" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="G_NOT" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="G_KISI" />
                  <asp:SessionParameter Name="login" SessionField="login" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="NOT_ID" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SONUC_KOD" />
                </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
              <asp:GridView ID="ChildGridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="NOT_ID" Visible="False"
              DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >  
               <Columns>
               <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True"/>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Not No">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="LabelNotID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NOT_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>

               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Görüşülen">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="LabelGorKisi" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("G_KISI") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Görüşen">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="LabelGrKisi" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OPERATOR") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Söz. Tarih">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="LabelSozTarih" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("S_TARIH","{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Söz. Tutar">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="LabelSozTutar" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("S_TUTAR","{0:n2}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kur">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="LabelKur" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DOV_CINS") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Gör. Tarih">   
                 <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="LabelGorTarih" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("A_TARIH","{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}") %>'></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Söz Durum">   
                 <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="LabelSozDurum" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SONUC_ACK") %>'></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource7" runat="server" 
                  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlServerCstr %>" 
                  SelectCommand="SELECT SONUC_KOD, SONUC_ACK FROM P_SONUC WHERE (SONUC_KOD > 3 AND LANG = 1) OR (SONUC_KOD < 0 AND LANG = 1)" >
                   </asp:SqlDataSource>
                  <asp:DropDownList id="lstSONUC" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="false" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource7"
                  DataTextField="SONUC_ACK" DataValueField="SONUC_KOD"
                  SelectedValue='<%# BIND("SONUC_KOD") %>'>
                  </asp:DropDownList>
                 </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Not">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="TxtNot" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("G_NOT") %>' Height="35" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="True">
                  </asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>
               </asp:GridView>

               <asp:DetailsView id="MemoDetailView" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4"
                Runat="Server" AutoGenerateRows="False" Visible="False" OnModeChanged="MemoDetailView_ModeChanged"> 
                <Fields>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Görüşülen">  
                 <InsertItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtG_KISI" Text='<%# Bind("G_KISI") %>' 
                      runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                  </InsertItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>  

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Söz Tarihi">        
                     <InsertItemTemplate>
               <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtSTR_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                  Enabled="True" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtSTR" 
                  PopupButtonID="ImageButton4" PopupPosition="BottomLeft">
                </cc1:CalendarExtender>
                <br />
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSTR" Text = '<%# Bind("S_TARIH") %>' runat="server" Height="16px" Width="85px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                     <asp:Image ID="ImageButton4" runat="server"
                        ImageUrl="~/images/SmallCalendar.gif"/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField> 

                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Ödeme Tutarı">  
                 <InsertItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtTutar" Text='<%# Bind("S_TUTAR") %>' 
                      runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                  </InsertItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>  

                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Kur">   
                 <InsertItemTemplate>
                 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" 
                  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlServerCstr %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [DOV_KOD],[DOV_CINS] FROM [Scania].[dbo].[P_KUR] ORDER BY [DOV_CINS]">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                  <asp:DropDownList id="lstKur" runat="server"
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6"
                  DataTextField="DOV_CINS" DataValueField="DOV_KOD"
                  SelectedValue='<%# BIND("DOV_KOD") %>'>
                  </asp:DropDownList>
                 </InsertItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>

                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Not">  
                 <InsertItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtG_NOT" Text='<%# Bind("G_NOT") %>' 
                      TextMode="multiline" runat="server" Height="100"></asp:TextBox>
                  </InsertItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>  

                </Fields>
                </asp:DetailsView>

            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
          </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:BoundField DataField="TEMSILCI_ACK" HeaderText="TEMSİLCİ" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="TEMSILCI_ACK" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" >

<ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>

          <asp:BoundField DataField="DOVIZ_CINS" HeaderText="KUR" 
            SortExpression="DOVIZ_CINS" readonly="true"/>

          <asp:BoundField DataField="0-30" HeaderText="0-30" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="0-30" DataFormatString="{0:n2}" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="31-60" HeaderText="31-60" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="31-60" DataFormatString="{0:n2}"/>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="61-90" HeaderText="61-90" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="61-90" DataFormatString="{0:n2}"/>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="90+" HeaderText="90+" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="90+" DataFormatString="{0:n2}"/>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="TOPLAM" HeaderText="TOPLAM" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="TOPLAM" DataFormatString="{0:n2}"/>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="TOP_GECIKME" HeaderText="GECİK. FAİZİ" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TOP_GECIKME" DataFormatString="{0:n2}"/>
   <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="FAALIYET_ACK" HeaderText="FAALİYET" 
            SortExpression="FAALIYET_ACK" readonly="true" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" >
          <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:BoundField>--%>
      <%--    <asp:BoundField DataField="TEMSILCI_ACK" HeaderText="TEMSİLCİ" 
            SortExpression="TEMSILCI_ACK" readonly="true" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" >       
          <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:BoundField>--%>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="STATÜ" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Blue">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlServerCstr %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT B.T_ST_ID, B.T_ST_ACK, C.T_SR_ID, C.T_SR_ACK, 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.NOTER_TAR,103) AS NOTER_TAR, 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.ICRA_TAR,103) AS ICRA_TAR, 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.HACIZ_TAR,103) AS HACIZ_TAR, A.YAK_EMIR, D.SONUC_ACK, A.T_NOT
                FROM TAKIP A, P_TAKIP_ST B, P_TAKIP_SR C, P_SONUC D
                WHERE A.T_STATU = B.T_ST_ID
                AND A.T_SRM = C.T_SR_ID
                AND A.YAK_EMIR = D.SONUC_KOD
                AND B.LANG = 1
                AND D.LANG = 1
                AND T_HESAP_NO = @T_HESAP_NO ">
                <SelectParameters>
                  <asp:Parameter Name="T_HESAP_NO" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
              </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSTATU" runat="server">
            </asp:Label>           
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlServerCstr %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT B.T_ST_ID, B.T_ST_ACK, C.T_SR_ID, C.T_SR_ACK, 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.NOTER_TAR,103) AS NOTER_TAR, 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.ICRA_TAR,103) AS ICRA_TAR, 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.HACIZ_TAR,103) AS HACIZ_TAR, A.YAK_EMIR, D.SONUC_ACK, A.T_NOT
                FROM TAKIP A, P_TAKIP_ST B, P_TAKIP_SR C, P_SONUC D
                WHERE A.T_STATU = B.T_ST_ID
                AND A.T_SRM = C.T_SR_ID
                AND A.YAK_EMIR = D.SONUC_KOD
                AND B.LANG = 1
                        AND D.LANG = 1
                AND T_HESAP_NO = @T_HESAP_NO ">
                <SelectParameters>
                  <asp:Parameter Name="T_HESAP_NO" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
              </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:DropDownList id="lstSTATU" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
            DataTextField="T_ST_ACK" DataValueField="T_ST_ID" Enabled="True" 
                Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Small"
            >
            </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
          </asp:TemplateField>     

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SORUMLU" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Blue" ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSRM" runat="server">
            </asp:Label>           
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
              <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" 
              ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlServerCstr %>" 
              SelectCommand="SELECT [T_SR_ID], [T_SR_ACK], T_ST_ID FROM [P_TAKIP_SR]"
               FilterExpression="T_ST_ID = '{0}'">
              <FilterParameters>
              <asp:ControlParameter Name="categoryParam" ControlID="lstSTATU" 
                   PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
              </FilterParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:DropDownList id="lstSORUMLU" runat="server"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5"
            DataTextField="T_SR_ACK" DataValueField="T_SR_ID" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                Font-Size="Small">
            </asp:DropDownList>      
            </EditItemTemplate>
          <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
          <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:TemplateField>    


          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NOTER TAR." ItemStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Blue">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtNTR_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                  Enabled="True" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtNTR" 
                  PopupButtonID="ImageButton1" PopupPosition="BottomLeft">
                </cc1:CalendarExtender>
                <br />
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtNTR" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="85px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                     <asp:Image ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"
                        ImageUrl="~/images/SmallCalendar.gif"/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblNTR" runat="server">
            </asp:Label>           
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:TemplateField>  

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="İCRA TAR." ItemStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Blue">
            <EditItemTemplate>
              <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtITR_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                  Enabled="True" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtITR" 
                  PopupButtonID="ImageButton2" PopupPosition="BottomLeft">
                </cc1:CalendarExtender>
                <br />
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtITR" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="85px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                     <asp:Image ID="ImageButton2" runat="server"
                        ImageUrl="~/images/SmallCalendar.gif"/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>           
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblITR" runat="server">
            </asp:Label>           
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:TemplateField>  

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FİİLİ HACİZ TAR." ItemStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Blue">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtHTR_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                  Enabled="True" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtHTR" 
                  PopupButtonID="ImageButton3" PopupPosition="BottomLeft">
                </cc1:CalendarExtender>
                <br />
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtHTR" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="85px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                     <asp:Image ID="ImageButton3" runat="server"
                        ImageUrl="~/images/SmallCalendar.gif"/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblHTR" runat="server">
            </asp:Label>           
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:TemplateField>  

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="YAK. EMRİ" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Blue">
            <EditItemTemplate>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="lstYEM" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" DataTextField="SONUC_ACK" 
                DataValueField="SONUC_KOD" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Small">
              </asp:DropDownList>
              <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlServerCstr %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [P_SONUC] WHERE ([SONUC_KOD] &lt; @SONUC_KOD)AND LANG = 1">
                <SelectParameters>
                  <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="4" Name="SONUC_KOD" Type="Int16" />
                </SelectParameters>
              </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblYEM" runat="server">
            </asp:Label>           
            </ItemTemplate>

        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>

          </asp:TemplateField>  

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NOT" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Blue" ItemStyle-Wrap="False">

            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txlbTNOT" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true" TextMode="MultiLine">
            </asp:TextBox>           
            </ItemTemplate>

            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTNOT" runat="server" Height="35" TextMode="MultiLine" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource8" runat="server" 
              ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlServerCstr %>" 
              SelectCommand="SELECT [T_NOT] FROM [TAKIP] WHERE T_HESAP_NO = @T_HESAP_NO ">
                <SelectParameters>
                  <asp:Parameter Name="T_HESAP_NO" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>

          <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
          <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:TemplateField>    

        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Blue" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
      </asp:GridView>
```

What i want is, classic `Header` freeze pane when i scroll down AND after `TEMSİLCİ` column freeze pane when i scroll right. (TEMSİLCİ column should stable, other columns moves when i scroll right)

Is it possible with CSS or other way?

Comment: Why Sorry, even more big codes are available in this site

Comment: If you have a budget, Telerik RadGrid (http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx) has an "option for static headers and static columns".

Comment: Or you could try to figure out how Telerik does it at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/frozencolumns/defaultcs.aspx .

Comment: @John Is this Telerik free? And how can i add Telerik.Web.UI Namespace to my page?

Comment: I question why you are pursuing "hacking" the gridview rather than coding your own table to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to freeze Headers easily and had have some luck with freezing any column you want.  But horizontal scroll is an issue.  For headers I have used Css and for columns I am manipulating css with help of jquery.  With more tweaking it can be achieved.

```
<div class="container">
<asp:GridView ID="grdview_items" runat="server"
DataSourceID="SDS_items" 
EnableViewState="false" Width="800">
<HeaderStyle  CssClass="grdview_headers"  />
 <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-Width="200px"  HeaderText="Item1"><ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="300px" ItemStyle-Width="300px"   HeaderText="Item2"><ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="300px" ItemStyle-Width="300px"    HeaderText="Item3"><ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
<style>
.container 
{
    overflow:auto;
    margin-left:10px;
    height:300px; 
    width:710px;
 }

.grdview_headers
{
    color:#330000; 
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:790px;
    margin-top:-1px;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.container tr>td:nth-child(2)').css("background-color", "#EAEAEA").css("position", "absolute");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Mitul Which version Jquery i must to add my project? And I don't want your color code. It's ok for me right?

Comment: @Soner Gonul - I recommend using latest version 1.5.1.  The colors you can change to whatever you like.  You can change background-color.

Comment: @Soner Gonul - Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297306/two-dimensional-scrollable-table

Comment: @Mitul Your code didn't work. Look at this http://jsbin.com/etiri5/edit . I'm looking now this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297306/two-dimensional-scrollable-table

Comment: @Mitul Some part works but it looks weird http://i1103.hizliresim.com/2011/3/14/8477.jpg

Comment: @Sooner for the header that is moving out of the div control header width with the help of item style width property. Make sure both these are same  HeaderStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-Width="200px" . Add these properties to all <itemtemplate> blocks.

Comment: This almost worked. My TH were all shrunk and the table went out of the gridview in IE10.