# Datagridview frozen header row

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I know that it's possible in winforms, to make the header row of Datagrid frozen when the user scroll down.
Is it also possible in webforms Datagridview?
I would like something clean that really works and looks pro.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this SO answer with frozen gridview header row and columns to some extent.

[Gridview with Freeze Panes Horizontal and Vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232844/gridview-with-freeze-panes-horizontal-and-vertical/5274810#5274810)